# How do I keep the cell blank in excel instead of showing a formula until data is entered?

Tags: excel

As of right now, the cell is displaying #DIV/0!.  It has a formula assigned to it that is =E6/B6*100%.  I need that cell to be blank until data is entered into cells E6 and B6.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula instead:

```
=IFERROR(E6/B6*100%,"")
```